# CUDA vs tensor cores in high FLOPs settings

Tags: performance, gpu, nvidia-graphics-card

RTX2080S trains x1.6 faster than GTX1070 for small models. For a model with 1+ TFLOPS, however, it trains **x6** faster - and I can't understand why.

The RTX has only x1.6 as many cores as the GTX ([3072](https://www.techpowerup.com/gpu-specs/geforce-rtx-2080-super.c3439) vs [1920](https://www.techpowerup.com/gpu-specs/geforce-gtx-1070.c2840)) and similar clock speeds, but with RTX having 384 tensor cores. [Benchmark comparison](https://gpu.userbenchmark.com/Compare/Nvidia-RTX-2080S-Super-vs-Nvidia-GTX-1070/4050vs3609) doesn't show any figure at 500%+  however.

Is this expected, and if so, how's it explained? Do tensor cores just have that much greater "FLOP capacity"?

**Setting**: automatic mixed precision, PyTorch; same software (OS, Anaconda environments), models, datasets; RAM and VRAM not saturated. "Training" = applying bunch of math on input arrays, "bigger model" = more math on more data (*at the same time*, i.e. in parallel).

Comment: The 2080S, being a "super" part, might support packing multiple 8-bit or 16-bit values into a single register for doing a batch operation while the 1070 is limited to 32 or 64 bit single values per operation irrespective of the actual data size. Combined with a boost to memory speed could be a significant change in performance.

Comment: https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/performance/mixed-precision-training/index.html has some info on the tensor cores boosting mixed precision math